# MapServer point layer

Tags: symbology, mapserver

I am able to draw and create a WMS mapfile for POLYGON and LINE but not for a POINT, I am not sure what maybe the issue, can you assist

```
LAYER
    NAME    Country
    TYPE POINT
    EXTENT -25 -35 51 37
    CONNECTIONTYPE  POSTGIS
    CONNECTION  'host=localhost dbname=xxx user=xxxx password=xxx port=5432'
    DATA "geom from (SELECT geom, gid FROM education WHERE country = 'xxxx' AND electricity = 'Yes' AND water = 'Yes') as subquery USING unique gid USING srid=4326" 
    METADATA
        'wms_title' 'Country'
        'wms_server_version'    '1.1.0'
        'gml_include_items' 'all'
        'wms_include_items' 'all'
    END
    STATUS  OFF
    TRANSPARENCY 100
    PROJECTION
        'init=epsg:4326'
    END
    
    CLASS
        NAME    'Country'
        STYLE
            SYMBOL "circle"
            SIZE 16
            COLOR 255 0 0
            OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
        END
    END
END
```

Please assist...

Comment: Where is circle defined?

Answer (score 1):

You reference a symbol called circle, so make sure that your map file can find the definition of circle.

Classical way is to have your symbols in a separate file let's call it `symbols.sym` then in your MAP section reference its location like:

```
SYMBOLSET "../DefaultMapIncludes/symbols.sym"
```

In `symbols.sym` you'd define your symbols like:

```
SYMBOLSET
    SYMBOL
        NAME "circle"
        TYPE ellipse
        FILLED false
        POINTS
            1 1
        END
        ANCHORPOINT 0.5 0.5
    END
    SYMBOL
        NAME "circlef"
        TYPE ellipse
        FILLED true
        POINTS
            10 10
        END
        ANCHORPOINT 0.5 0.5
    END
    SYMBOL
        NAME "cross"
        TYPE vector
        POINTS
            2.0 0.0
            2.0 4.0
            -99 -99
            0.0 2.0
            4.0 2.0
        END
    END
    SYMBOL
        NAME "cross2"
        # This is a multiplies type cross
        TYPE vector
        POINTS
            0 0
            1 1
            -99 -99
            0 1
            1 0
        END
    END
    SYMBOL
        NAME "plus"
        # This is a plus type cross
        TYPE vector
        POINTS
            .5 0
            .5 1
            -99 -99
            0 .5
            1 .5
        END
    END
    SYMBOL
        NAME "squaref"
        TYPE vector
        POINTS
          0 0
          0 1
          1 1
          1 0
          0 0
        END
        FILLED true
        ANCHORPOINT 0.5 0.5
    END
        SYMBOL
        NAME "square"
        TYPE vector
        POINTS
            0 0
            0 1
            1 1
            1 0
            0 0
        END
        FILLED false
        ANCHORPOINT 0.5 0.5
    END
    SYMBOL
        NAME "dsquaref"
        TYPE vector
        POINTS
            0 2
            2 4
            4 2
            2 0
            0 2
        END
        FILLED true
        ANCHORPOINT 0.5 0.5
    END
    SYMBOL
        NAME "triangle"
        TYPE vector
        POINTS
           0 4
           2 0
           4 4
           0 4
        END
        FILLED false
    END
    SYMBOL
        NAME "trianglef"
        TYPE vector
        POINTS
           0 4
           2 0
           4 4
           0 4
        END
        FILLED true
    END
        SYMBOL
        NAME "dtrianglef"
        TYPE vector
        POINTS
            2 4
            4 0
            0 0
            2 4
        END
        FILLED true
    END
    SYMBOL
        NAME starf
        TYPE vector
        FILLED TRUE
        POINTS
            0 .375
            .35 .375
            .5 0
            .65 .375
            1 .375
            .75 .625
            .875 1
            .5 .75
            .125 1
            .25 .625
        END
    END
    SYMBOL
        NAME fatplusf
        TYPE vector
        FILLED TRUE
        POINTS
            0 1
            0 2
            1 2
            1 3
            2 3
            2 2
            3 2
            3 1
            2 1
            2 0
            1 0
            1 1
         END
    END
    SYMBOL
        NAME pentagonf
        TYPE vector
        FILLED TRUE
        POINTS
            0 .375
            .5 0
            1 .375
            .875 1
            .125 1
        END
    END
END
```

and then you can reference the symbol in your LAYER > CLASS > STYLE